# Exporting Bibliography from LaTex to MS Word

Tags: bibliographies

I have a document in LaTex but the template of the journal is in word. I have copied most of the text into word template. Now I am facing problem in Bibliography. Is there a way to export bibliography from my Latex file to MS Word Bibliography? I am using word 2013.

Comment: I take it the copying of "most of the text into word template" was successful, in the sense you were able to apply whatever formatting that was needed.  Assuming you were able to generate the bibliography via BibTeX, I suppose you could copy the contents of the bibliography, stored in the `.bbl` file, to your .docx file as well.

Comment: I did copy paste of the text--- very cumbersome. In LaTex document, I had used \cite{} and \bibitem{} for references.

Comment: Use `bibtex4word` : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bibtex4word+download&oq=bibtex4word&aqs=chrome.1.0l6.6841j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Which bibliography-related text did you copy -- the contents of the bib file, or those of the bbl file? By the way, please observe that I didn't claim that this copying busy was not going to be cumbersome.

Comment: I copied rest of the document. Now I want to add and manage references in word document. I didnot copy any text related to bibliography.

Comment: try to convert your file to `.odt` with `mk4ht oolatex filename`, you can then convert it in LibreOffice to Word

Comment: I had to to do soemthing like that few moths ago. I used pandoc installed with few plug ins for the right management of the bibliography. So I converted from `latex` to `markdown`once, and later from `markdown` to `docx`. I used JabRef for export my `.bib` file into word's `xml` format. Finally I uploaded that xml file and manually I changed the `bibtexkeys` by the right keys from the Word's database. Maybe you can find an easier way, but that one worked for me. Good luck.

Comment: Can you show a MWE? Without knowing which kind of bibliography you are using, this sounds hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the bibliograhy data in a bib-file have a look at [jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). That tool offers so many different export formats that one of them should help to solve your problem.